# Sidebar block randomly changing width

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal

I have a floating block on the right hand side here http://www.paleolife.co.uk/pi/79-2008518383

When you scroll down the width changes.  I have no idea why...anyone have any hints of where to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your width to be 168px declare it. When the position of the block changes from position: static, to fixed, it changes its properties and affects the width of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You're fixing your `.block` div which does not have a width set instead of your `#sidebar-second` which has a width of 240px so when you scroll down your `sidebar-second` div stays behind while your `.block` div is fixed to the screen with no width, so add a width to your `.block` div as well, e.g.

```
.sidebar .block {
   width:240px;
}
```